# executing a jar file brought in by maven using java Runtime object

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a java code that runs a jar file. To do that I am using the runtime object and create a process like:

```
Runtime re = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process jarProcess = re.exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","src/resources/myjar.jar"});
```

This works perfectly when I put my jar file in `src/resources/myjar.jar`. Now I want to improve this and instead of putting the jar file in the resources, I want to add a dependency to that jar in my .pom file and then use the jar file that maven pulls in. But I don't know how to do this. It seems that even when I hardcode my maven remote directory which is something like ~/.m2/... the process cannot be run. I don't get any error (unless I'm missing something) but the `jarProcess.exitValue()` is 1. So how can I update my code to refer and execute the jar file which is pulled in by Maven.

Comment: So many questions .  A jar file, embedded within your app won't be executable when the project is built and packaged.  You'd need to "extract" the jar file and store it somewhere externally instead.  I don't think you want the Jar as a dependency, in the sense that Maven considers it, and placing the Jar in the resources folder should allow maven to package it into the resulting package/bundle of your app

Comment: I strongly recommend to remove such strange approach (having a jar file inside src/main/resource) and calling it externally. What is the reason for such an approach? Apart from that strange approach I would recommend to use ProcessBuilder instead of exec...